# Converting List to JSON in Java with correct extension

Tags: java, json, servlets, header, gson

I am trying to create a `List` of errors with different codes and converting them to `JSON` using `gson`.

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(Errors.getErrors());
```

And here is the class:

```
public class Errors {

    private static List<SingleError> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    public static List<SingleError> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public static void addError(SingleError singleError) {
        errors.add(singleError);
    }

}
```

**The output I get:**

```
[
    {
        "code": "bad_signal"
    }
]
```

**The output I need:**

```
{
   "errors": [
       {
          "code": "bad_signal"
       }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing in the `Errors` class the get the output I need? 
It would be better if it would be added in the class without just adding string to json conversion.

**EDIT** 
As schomsel suggested, I should use this line to get the output I need.

```
gson.toJson(Collections.singletonMap("errors", Errors.getErrors()))
```

And it did work but I failed to mention that I am also using `Servlet` to return the String and setting this header, which deletes the "errors".

```
resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

What is the correct header I need to use here?

Comment: You could do `Collections.singletonMap("errors", Errors.getErrors())`. But it's usually better to avoid `static` if possible.

Comment: @shmosel if I put it in the gson.toJson(Collections.singletonMap("errors", Errors.getErrors())). I still get the same result. It looks like it should be correct but?

Comment: @shmosel The output stays the same because I'm using `Servlet` to return the string with this line `resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`. The actual string itself is correct. What do i need to return for it to look like the output I need? Is it a Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you should understand that desired json representation is for `Errors` class itself and not contained `erros` list only so your code is to be tweaked so you can pass `Errors` class instance as input to - `gson.toJson(...)`

Two solutions ,

First Solution - make `Errors` fields and methods non - static and pass on `Errors` instance instead of `errors` List to call - `gson.toJson(ErrorsInstance);`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

class Errors {  
 private List<SingleError> errors = new ArrayList<>();
 public List<SingleError> getErrors() {
            return errors;
 }

 public void addError(SingleError singleError) {
            errors.add(singleError);
 }
```

Second Solution - if fields & methods can't be made static then add a new method to get `Errors` instance via private constructor and then create `Gson` object from `GsonBuilder` so that static fields can be included during serialization.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

class Errors {


   // private constructor 
    private Errors(List<SingleError> errors) {
        Errors.errors = errors;
    }

    private static List<SingleError> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    public static List<SingleError> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

   // New method to return Errors instance 
    public static Errors getErrorsInstance() {
        return new Errors(errors);
    }

    public static void addError(SingleError singleError) {
        errors.add(singleError);
    }

    }
```

//To include static fields during serialization & ignore only transient fields- if not done then json would be empty

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        // Allowing the serialization of static fields
    gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.TRANSIENT);
    // Creates a Gson instance based on the current configuration
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        Errors errorsInstance = Errors.getErrorsInstance();
        String jsonStringTest = gson.toJson(errorsInstance );
```

**EDIT:**

For Second solution, you wouldn't need a private constructor & new method - `getErrorsInstance()` . You can simply feed `new Errors()` to `gson.toJson(...)` . What you need is only static field inclusion in deserialization & same would hold true for solution # 1 too. So you don't need to modify any code, just make sure with `GsonBuilder` that static fields are included & pass on `Errors` instance instead of contained list.

Comment: I tried the first solution and it worked, but do you mind explaining why `static` list gives one answer and `instance` from the `Errors` gives another?

Comment: @kataroty : I have provided an edit to answer. Basically , `GsonBuilder` configuration is all you need.